# Validating my experiment design and Mann-Whitney U test usage

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

There are four different methods I use to generate *solutions* for different *domains*.
To determine which solution is the most useful, I want to conduct an experiment with participants.
As I have some limitations about the execution of the experiment, such as how long it should take each participant to participate, I considered the following experiment.  To simplify, let me denote these first: $Participants=\{P_1...P_{37}\}, Solutions=\{S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4\}, Domain=\{D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4\}$. As a next step, I would like to assign two domains ($D_k, D_j$) to each $P_i$. Then I want to ask them which of two possible solutions ($S_k, S_j$) is better for each domain $D_k$. This is what it should look like:

| domain/solution | $S_1 VS\ S_2$ | $S_1 VS\ S_3$ | $S_1 VS\ S_4$ | $S_2 VS\ S_3$ | $S_2 VS\ S_4$ | $S_3 VS\ S_4$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $D_1$ | $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ | $\{P_4,P_5,P_6\}$ | $\{P_7,P_8,P_9\}$ | $\{P_{10},P_{11},P_{12}\}$ | $\{P_{13},P_{14},P_{15}\}$ | $\{P_{16},P_{17},P_{18}\}$ |
| $D_2$ | $\{P_{16},P_{17},P_{18}\}$ | $\{P_{13},P_{14},P_{12}\}$ | $\{P_{10},P_{11},P_{12}\}$ | $\{P_7,P_8,P_9\}$ | $\{P_4,P_5,P_6\}$ | $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ |
| $D_3$ | $\{P_{20},P_{21},P_{22}\}$ | $\{P_{23},P_{24},P_{25}\}$ | $\{P_{26},P_{27},P_{28}\}$ | $\{P_{29},P_{30},P_{31}\}$ | $\{P_{32},P_{33},P_{34}\}$ | $\{P_{35},P_{36},P_{37}\}$ |
| $D_4$ | $\{P_{35},P_{36},P_{37}\}$ | $\{P_{32},P_{33},P_{34}\}$ | $\{P_{29},P_{30},P_{31}\}$ | $\{P_{26},P_{27},P_{28}\}$ | $\{P_{23},P_{24},P_{25}\}$ | $\{P_{20},P_{21},P_{22}\}$ |

Each cell contains participants who will choose between the two solutions. (e.g. $\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}$ will decide who is better $S_1$ or $S_2$ in $D_1$, and $S_3$ or $S_4$ in $D_2$).

Next, I want to apply the **Mann-Whitney U test** to each column in the table above. For example for the column $S_1 VS\ S_2$ it would look like this:

| particapte\soultion | $S_1$ | $S_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $P_1$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_2$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_3$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_{16}$ | 0 | 1 |
| $P_{17}$ | 0 | 1 |
| $P_{18}$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_{20}$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_{21}$ | 0 | 1 |
| $P_{22}$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_{35}$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_{36}$ | 1 | 0 |
| $P_{37}$ | 1 | 0 |

Finally, I want to show this table, where the values indicate that there is a statistically significant difference between the solutions.

|  | $S_1$ | $S_2$ | $S_3$ | $S_4$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $S_1$ | X | 0.01 | 0.06 | 0.5 |
| $S_2$ | X | X | 0.02 | 0.05 |
| $S_3$ | X | X | X | 0.1 |
| $S_4$ | X | X | X | X |

I am wondering if this methodology is valid to determine if different solutions perform better than others and if so, which one does that better than others.

In an ideal world, I would ask each participant to rate all the solutions for each domain and then apply the Friedman test and post-hoc analysis. However, since I want to keep the questionnaire simple, I will ask participants for only two out of four solutions and two domains.